# Setup www as main domain on Cloudflare

Tags: domains, dns, cdn, cloud

I'm trying to setup Cloudflare so my `www` subdomain doesn't redirect to the `http` naked domain and do exactly the opposite:
`mydomain.com` redirecting to `www.mydomain.com`

Cloudflare automatically configures the DNS records this way:

```
Type: A
Name: 'mydomain'
Value: 'public ip number'

Type: CNAME
Name: www
Value: alias of `mydomain`
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFlare is setting up the domain. Since it is used to work with the main domain. Techincally speaking the "www." prefix is always a subdomain/CNAME/alias of the main domain.

You're all fine with CloudFlare configuring the domain without www since you're able to control both the non-www and www part of it.

So for the DNS settings, everything looks fine. Now for the eventually used redirects from non-www to www, you can take a look into CloudFlare page rules.